# facebook open-graph html is malformed?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

the error message is

> Errors That Must Be Fixed
>
> Meta Tags In Body: Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the
>   head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower
>   in the parse tree. Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable.

however my link here, clearly has the

```
<head> og:tags </head>
```

format in proper order, any ideas for this funky message from fb?

Comment: Your html is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fofwgkta.co.uk%2Fauction_details.php%3Fname%3DDoing-Research-in-Political-Science-An-Introduction-to-Comparative-Methods-and-Statistics%26auction_id%3D111292&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook won't share a link to my site](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13185406/facebook-wont-share-a-link-to-my-site)

Comment: can you further elaborate cpilko, what tags are making the html invalid

Comment: thanks, I used http://validator.w3.org/ to check my html

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `meta` tag inside `head` tag.